# cannot use instance member 'ref' with the initializer error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing this error all is well, I want to print the children of "12356" in console but i am getting this error i dont know why this is happening and here is the **Firebase structure
[image]**

and this is the xcode error
[image]

and here is the code

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseDatabase

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


var ref  = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


let root = ref.child("Items").child("Flate").child("12356")

root.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

if !snapshot.exists() { return }

//print(snapshot)

if let myfRateA = snapshot.value["fRateA"] as? String {
print(myfRateA)
}
if let myfRateB = snapshot.value["fRateB"] as? String {
print(myfRateB)
}
})


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: _please help me instead of vote down_ is not what you should add in a title. I suggest your edit that out.

Comment: Ok dear i know its out but i did so i am updating now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not put your code into the right place, because it is outside any method or function. Put it inside a function's body like so:

```
func printChildren(){

let ref  = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


let root = ref.child("Items").child("Flate").child("12356")

root.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

if !snapshot.exists() { return }

//print(snapshot)

let myfRateA = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["fRateA"] as? String ?? ""
print(myfRateA)
let myfRateB = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["fRateB"] as? String ?? ""
print(myfRateB)

})

}
```

And call it in **`viewDidLoad()`** like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.printChildren()
}
```

Comment: still i am getting an error:  type subscript has no any member

Comment: @Max on what line??

Comment: thanxfor your support but still getting an error  type 'Any?' has no subscript  member

Comment: where? Please specify the line on which you are getting this error!

Comment: 35 and 38 line where if condition of both chid

Comment: looking over that, please wait

Comment: @Max i have updated the answer, try it out now. The problem was that you weren't accessing your values correctly! Please check the answer and respond!

Comment: Thankyou so muchhhhhhhh :)

Comment: @Max You're welcome! If you have any other question related to this, just ask.

Comment: Good luck programming!